# Return some middle portion if length is over x?

Tags: regex

I'm currently using a RegEx like so `(.{12}$)|(^.{1,12}$)` - something like "*if the value is 1 to 12 long, return them, else return the last 12.*"

I'm looking to add another clause, where if the length is greater than 16, I need to return a subset of it (specifically, starting at the 5th character, return 12).

How can I do this within the same RegEx?

Comment: your trying to get up to twelve characters from the end or something else? Isn't the single (.{1,12}$) enough?

Comment: `If the length is 1 to 12 digits, return them. Else, return last 12.` is currently implemented. I want to edit it, to make it `If the length is 1 to 12 digits, return them. If the length is greater than 16 digits, return 12 digits starting at the 5th digit. Else, return last 12.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work with

```
(?<=^.{4}).{12}|^.{1,12}$
```

This contains two parts. The first one handles strings at least 16 characters in length. For that it starts matching at the fifth character (that's what the `(?<=^.{4})` is for – ensuring that there are exactly four characters preceding). After that there have to be at least 12 characters which are matched.

The second part is just for strings with 1–12 characters, matching the complete string.

Quick PowerShell test:

```
PS> '12345','1234567890','abcdefghijklmnopqrst'|%{if($_-match'(?<=^.{4}).{12}|^.{1,12}$'){$Matches}}

Name                           Value
----                           -----
0                              12345
0                              1234567890
0                              efghijklmnop
```

Comment: I added one more clause to it, but it works perfectly. I'm using `(?<=^.{4}).{12}|^.{1,12}$|.{12}$` to cover the base of an input between 12 and 16 digits, it should just return the last 12. Thank you! :D

Comment: Hrm, having some more trouble. If I feed it an input of `123456789012345678901234567890`, it matches two times - last 12 and mid 12. Any idea how I can get it to not match the last 12 if it finds a match earlier?

Comment: That depends on how you match. Either always use the first match (if you're finding all matches) or use a function that only returns the first match (e.g. `Matcher.find` in Java, or `Regex.Match` in .NET).

Comment: D'oh, yeah, I was concerned you would refer back to the code. The code in this project is likely a VB6, or similarly antiquated VB, running on Windows CE devices. The RegEx in question is modified by changing values in `settings` Tables, and we were hoping to achieve this result by tinkering them instead of contacting those contractors again. Is there no way to do it directly in the RegEx?

Comment: You could use something like `(?<=^.{4}).{12}|^.{1,12}$|(?<=^.{1,3}).{12}$` which should match only once (i.e. cannot take two alternatives at the same time).

Comment: That doesn't seem to match anything for me. :( http://www.myregextester.com/?r=f940bcf2

Comment: Mh, which regex engine is used there? Most cannot cope with variable-length lookbehind. JavaScript falls into that category which is why that site cannot work. But if it's .NET it should work.

Comment: Oh. Hm. I'm fairly certain it's some flavour of VB, not sure if it's .NET or not. I'll toss it into the Settings and see how it does.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you for having the insight to point out it won't work in JS. Works fantastic on our application. You've saved me so much headache! Thanks!